# How can I integrate the DX100 controller to my laptop?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Im a beginner at ROS and currently working in i project at my university where I should be able to send signals (go and stop signals at first) to a robot (Yakshawa Motoman robot) via the DX100 controller.

wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials says I need ROS hydro+. Does it work for ROS groovy as well or do I need to install the hydro+ version?

This page wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver#Requirements also says that I should mail to some group to get the MotoPlus SDK and some Motoman Part number. Is this necessary or do I need to mail them?

Thank you for all your help!

/Beginner who is lost... =)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83001/how-can-i-integrate-the-dx100-controller-to-my-laptop?/) by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The driver does work with groovy but must be downloaded from source.  The industrial core library would also need to be downloaded from source as well. The groovy_devel branch should be used.  The wiki instructions should apply to these source version.

You should still work with Motoman to ensure your controller is configure correctly

FYI, we are nearing a hydro release and are in the process of updating the wikis. If you run into any issues, please ask another question.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on 2013-09-25**:
Hi again!

If we need to controll our robot do we need to install the server application on the controller or can we use the interface immediatly? What about the robot ip? How can we establish a connection? The controller software is updated to the latest version.

At gthub it says if we use groovy we should checkout the svn repo, is this relevant?

Many thanks!

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2013-09-29**:
The server must be installed: http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/InstallServer
To connect from a ROS-I PC, follow these: http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Usage.

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2013-09-29**:
The svn repo contains the released groovy version.  The git groovy_devel branch contains the latest version that works with groovy (and what will become the hydro release).

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2013-09-29**:
Also, sorry for the short replies, the comments aren't made for providing long winded answers.  Please ask another question if you need more info or post it to the ROS-I list. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev